Purpose of async/await in web servers
I don't understand why I keep seeing async/await recommended (or sometimes, even enforced) for ASP.NET Core web applications and APIs.
As far as I can tell, every request is already being run on a thread pool (as empirically tested by logging the thread ID during each request), so making all calls use async/await within your webmethods will, at best, move the execution from your thread pool to a different thread pool.
It doesn't free up the socket, because, well the connection is still open and the client is still waiting (synchronously or not) for a response.
There must be something I don't get, but what?

Hi, this is called the reactor pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern (the wikipedia page is not that great, you may want to google instead)

Tasks (sync contexts) are just lighter and cheaper than Threads.  Threads virtualize your Cores, Tasks virtualize your Threads.

@HenkHolterman Threads virtualize your Cores, Tasks virtualize your Threads  - That is an excellent description.


As far as I can tell, every request is already being run on a thread
pool (as empirically tested by logging the thread ID during each
request), so making all calls use async/await within your webmethods
will, at best, move the execution from your thread pool to a different
thread pool.

The 2nd part of the assumption is incorrect. The async / await calls, assuming they are IO calls, will not be offloaded to a different thread pool thread.
Essentially, while IO happens, the thread that encountered an await will be free to pick up other requests. This improves the throughput of the web application. The fundamental reason behind this is that IO is not done by the CPU but by the various IO devices on the PC (disk, network card, etc.); the CPU merely coordinates them. Synchronous calls will simply block the application thread waiting (essentially meaning one CPU core—it doesn't matter which—is performing the sync wait—OS scheduling has little effect on this outcome) for the IO device to finish, which is not an ideal measure for maximum throughput.
This is a pretty good read on the matter:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

It doesn't free up the socket, because, well the connection is still
open and the client is still waiting (synchronously or not) for a
response.

A simplified view:
Your server will bind a listener on a port (80 or 443 usually). When a request comes in, a new socket is created for every single connection (you can't have the same socket shared between 2 clients). The simplified workflow is like this:

Server binds listener port.
Connection incoming
Socket is created between server and client.
Request is assigned to a thread pool thread, and processing begins -> this is where your async happens.
Listener is again free to serve a new connection. Repeat 2-4

Note that steps 4 and 5 happen in parallel.
Async in step 4 allows the physical thread to pick up multiple sockets from the listener.
There's a hard limit on how many requests can be processed at the same time. As you correctly identified, there is a limit on how many sockets you can have open, and you cannot simply close the socket on someone. That is true. However, the limit of sockets is in the range of tens of thousands, whereas the limit on threads is in the thousands. So in order to fully saturate your sockets, which is ideal 100% usage of hardware, you need to better manage your threads, which is where async-await comes in.
When a thread processing at step 4 encounters an await on async IO, it will simply return to the pool and be ready to process another request. The async IO device will send a notification to the CPU when it is done, so the processing of the request that was interrupted can continue. In the case of web APIs, the thread continuing after an await is not always the thread that encountered the await. This can be configured using ConfigureAwait on applications that do care about thread affinity (not the case for web API). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097471/what-does-synchronizationcontext-do and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext for more details.
You can imagine this as a clown juggling 3-4 balls with just one hand. The thread is the clown. The balls in the air are async IO that are handled by IO devices. The ball in the clown's hand is the request currently being actively processed by that thread. If the clown wasn't allowed to throw balls in the air he'd be limited by the number of hands (one in this case) on how many balls he can handle.
Some more clarifications from comments:

IO is async in nature. The synchronous IO wait happens in the application level APIs and libraries (even if they are provided by the OS).
Async-await allows applications to fully adapt to the async nature of IO.
We are not talking about Task.Run here, its use case is different, async-await is used there for convenience.


In the case of most dotnet web API hosts (including IIS and kestrel), all requests are executed in the default synronization context (the threadpool), and so ConfigureAwait does nothing. IO will always resume on any available thread in the pool, with no attempt to pin.

It is usually only in the desktop synchronization contexts (WinForms/WPF) where the concept of the event loop thread is important that it will resume on the original thread by default.

The clown analogy could do with more clowns, throwing balls to each other (although that is still coordinating too early)

@user1937198 Didnt want to dive too much into that rabbit hole, added some links for further reading.

@Caleth Another analogy is waiting for a deliveryman. If you are async, you will only have to open the door when the bell rings. If you are sync, you simply camp the door and do nothing else waiting for the delivery, meaning all your chores are not done. But clowns are better.

Another good analogy is a single baker with 3 ovens.  After putting some bread in the first oven to cook, they can prepare some more dough to put the second oven.  After than they can prepare some dough for the 3rd oven.  Once that's done, the bread might be ready to come out of the first oven.  That's asynchronous.  The synchronous version would be having the baker put bread in the first oven and then stand there doing nothing while the bread cooks.  You need 3 times as many bakers in the synchronous approach get the same production rate as the asynchronous approach.


Synchronous calls will simply block the CPU core waiting for the IO device to finish

Why can't the OS kernel scheduler take the thread off the CPU core while it's waiting for an interrupt and replace it with a different thread?

@bdsl The first link explains that IO si async in nature. The actual blocking occurs in the application layer, so the OS cannot randomly reschedule threads. It is not a specific CPU core that gets blocked in reality but this is an overly simplified explanation.

@bdsl It can and it does, but the application thread that issued the IO request will still block. This means that synchronous IO still limits you to a number of in-flight requests equal to the number of threads in your thread pool, but threads run into scalability issues much faster than IO requests do (that is, you can have far more IO requests in flight than you can have threads, largely because of how much memory threads need), so you can generally serve a very large number of concurrent requests with less overall resources by making the IO asynchronous.

Blocking IO will not block the CPU core, it will only block the thread. The CPU is free to do work for other threads.

A lot of talk about I/O, but if anyone imagines File I/O, it's not at all clear why async would be desirable. An async, sequential File I/O is actually probably exactly what OP is imagining as a wasted async call.

await/async isn't normally useful if you're just moving the processing to another thread on the CPU. Normally you'll move the work to another device (a network machine, a GPU, etc)

Good answer, so it makes no sense to add another one. But you could improve it just a little by mentioning that the async/await construct leads to the state of the processing (when waiting for I/O) is simply stored in a data structure (generally, probably some kind of closure; I'm not familiar with how .net handles that or how it would be called there); this should make it clear(er) that while the waiting happens, there are no resources being kept "open" except a bit of RAM (and the low-level TCP/IP connection itself, of course, and whatever else is required to be open for the req itself).

@Mars If you’re only accessing one file and have nothing else to do at the time, then yeah, it’s wasted. But that’s a really rare case in most real world applications, because you’re almost never serving only a single request at a time, and it’s not unusual to need multiple read and/or write operations to service a given request (and, depending on the storage stack, a ‘sequential’ series of operations could possibly even be sped up by parallelizing it within the same file).

@AustinHemmelgarn I think the advantage of concurrent operations is apparent to OP, so I'm only referring to the single operation use case. That said, I think it's a rare case where parallel operations to the same file are faster than a single sequential operation. Maybe for sufficiently large files, if the file isn't locked (ie a write operation)....

@AustinHemmelgarn Async/await isn't going to help if threads are your bottleneck, unless you're moving the operation off the CPU (a network call, or processing on GPU, etc). If you have 8 threads, you could process 8 requests sequentially or you could process 1 request with 8 parallel CPU operations. Your throughput will be the same or worse (thread operation overhead).

@Ccm Any clarification regarding "IO is async by nature" ? I don't follow, maybe because I think you're using some specific definition of IO that differs from my understanding. You might want to define IO as well

@Mars please refer to the first link

@Ccm I'd rather not, that's why I'm saying it should be in the answer

Sorry, to rephrase that, I shouldn't have to read a giant article just to understand what your answer defines as I/O. But atter reading the answer, I still find it hard to believe that no thread is needed to move data from memory to disk. My knowledge of hardware is limited, but my understanding is that moving data from memory to disk will always still utilize the CPU. Guess I have something to research

Hmm, I stand corrected. It seems that the DMA mentioned does exactly that--it bypasses the CPU involvement so that the write can go directly from memory to disk. But of course that suggests that the write data already exists in memory, instead of being generated at write time.

@Mars It's not directly relevant to the topic of asyncio, but you might be interested in zero-copy approaches which avoid using the CPU at all.

A threadpool does not have infinite threads. Each time you synchronously wait, you are holding onto a thread and doing nothing with it.
If you instead await, the suspension will bubble up to the threadpool's work scheduler, which can then use that thread to do other work. When the underlying action becomes resumable, the scheduler will give you a (probably different) thread to continue on.

So it's moving the workload from a regular thread pool to a better-managed thread pool?

@Medinoc there's no workload. You move from having a blocked thread to not having a blocked thread.

@Medinoc Ideally at the bottom of the stack, you call a method that is doing some form of asynchronous IO. These APIs allow a single OS thread to wait for many logical tasks simultaneously. They mostly take the form of the IOCP API.

@Medinoc Consider that threads are large, often multiple MB overhead. At scale, that multiplies out to considerable memory usage. Also, traditional "one thread per connection" requires the OS to wake up that thread, crossing the kernel–userland boundary which can be expensive. Event driven I/O can sidestep a lot of this overhead, and async provides a convenient abstraction. All of this matters more when you have hundreds or thousands of concurrent tasks that are mostly waiting for IO to complete. With async, one thread per core is ideal, and other langs often get by with a single thread.

@Medinoc: it's not bad vs good, it's cooperative vs preemptive multitasking. With threads, once the thread goes you don't have to consider when another thread runs. The OS will occasionally suspend them, anywhere and switch to another, that's the preemption. Async/await is cooperative, and as that implies, requires everyone to play nice to make it all work. Ever time you can an awaitable function, you provide the complier an indication a spot where your code makes sense to pause and let another take a turn if they're ready.

I'm not convinced that having less threads is beneficial for IO bound workload.

@Basilevs: it is in certain situations. Threads are expensive to create, and especially expensive to context switch on. With async/await, context switching is super cheap, it's basically little more than an ordinary function call. Now for some situations the price of threads is not a big deal, if you are working on e.g. maybe a video editor, or CAD software or something, you might be doing a lot of IO, but you've really only got a handful of threads because you only have a small handful of things to do all at once.

In comparison, say you have a webserver, each individual request coming in might be fairly small in cost, but you have a bazillion of them coming in. Having them each on their own thread is logically simple and straightforward, but the cost of those threads, and those context switches can be severe, to the point of exceeding the amount of lifting you're doing on the actual servicing of requests. By switching to async/await, you can eliminate that context switching, at the price of reworking the flow to be in a cooperative multitasking design.

So your argument is, that threads are costly to create? Don't create threads then. Instead of using multiple small operations, group them in large blocks. Also, memory and CPU are irrelevant when IO dominates.

@Basilevs grouping multiple small operations like web requests into batches to process is really a lot more complicated than an async/await paradigm. Also that model is "notchy" you'll have a bunch of work that needs to be sent out all at once (when the batch completes) instead of when it becomes available (reactive pattern). The whole point of async await paradigm is to have the same throughput with fewer threads. The more I/O bound you are the more effective this becomes.

@basilevs also what would you do if your work in the batch had to wait for some other downstream I/O? Would you batch that work to before sending it downstream? I think you'd end up with quite suboptimal throughput in that scenario.

Batching is effectively async in terms of concept and performance. Grouping will have to be done in other ways. I agree  that this would not work for simple webserver, some workload is required for threads to stay effective.

@Basilevs "Don't create threads then. Instead of using multiple small operations, group them in large blocks." async/await is effectively syntactic sugar to do exactly that.

@Basilevs: as others said, that 'grouping' and managing of that is non-trivial to do right. You don't truly even need threads or any of this, you could get everything done with a single thread and use select() to handle all the IO. The only problem is that you'll go terminally insane trying to handle all the complexity. async/await is a tool that abstracts some of that complexity that is commonly encountered, just the same way functions, lambdas, for loops, etc all provides. You can skip all that and just write everything in x86 assembly if you want,

But people found it's better to use high level abstractions in most situations rather than going nuts.

It sounds to me like there are 2 wrong assumptions here.

The point of async/await isn't to free up the socket/connection. You're freeing up the thread to do other work during some async operation.

The point of async/await isn't to do long, synchronous work on another thread. You might await a database read across the network, so that the thread doesn't need to stall until the database responds (if it even does). You free up your thread so that other requests can be processed while you wait, then when your response has been delivered, you get added back into the processing queue, receive a thread and continue your work.
Async/await frees your threads with the assumption that someone else is going to work.


Let's pretend threads are humans and a microwave is a network call.
If you're heating something in the microwave, watching it until it's ready is "polling".
If you push a button and let it ring when it's done, that's an interrupt/signal.
Async/await is pushing the button, going to watch tv, then going back when the microwave tells you to.
Waiting for the signal frees you up, because you're delegating the heating to somewhere else (another machine). Heating is an asynchronous task.
But if your heating is synchronous (ie a person needs to do it), then you're basically  putting the food in a microwave, walking over to your tv, walking back to the microwave, taking the food out, rubbing it until it's warm, putting it back into the microwave, walking to the tv, walking back to the microwave, then finally taking the food out again.
A lot of pointless overhead.

Let's make this a little more web-specific.
You're probably awaiting a DB transaction network calls or other inter-process communication.
Rather than poll until those other actors are done, you say "hey, run the rest of this code when the other guy is done". (ie, scheduling a task to be run after some signal is received)

Its not about CPU work, the async stuff is not for processing. Its for IO.
Once you realise that, it becomes a little easier to accept. Its still pointless rubbish though as the async version of IO appears to be terribly slow so you're robbing Peter to pay Paul but with extortionate interest!
I think the async was added to help with responsiveness of UIs from the concept that became popular in Node (which needed it because node is single threaded). For a webserver, waiting on a thread even for IO, is not a problem (ie you'll run out of sockets or memory before the number of threads becomes an issue)
So all you do is make your request slower at the benefit of "responsiveness" which for webservers is not an issue - the only way to make your webserver feel more responsive is to complete the request as quickly as possible.
Don't forget, if you wait on IO using a single thread, Windows will not busy-wait that thread, you will wait on a synchronisation primitive and CPU will be free to process other threads. This applies to IO just as much, the OS syscall will block on an event for you.
The benefit appears to be trivially minor. You get to use fewer threads, but by the time you have too many threads, your system is overloaded and needs tuning to block incoming requests anyway. It adds nothing, but as we see from benchmarks, costs a lot. Async/await is a bad solution looking for a problem. its like spending $10 in order to save $5.

"you'll run out of sockets or memory before the number of threads becomes an issue" - citation needed

@Bergi these days, threads are limited by memory and CPU resources, of which we have an abundance. Sockets are limited to a 16-bit word per IP and most servers limited in file descriptors of which you need 1 per socket.
